# Match x, but not y anwywhere (not before, between or after the matching pattern)

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match several ways of writing a lastname, but that does not match firstname.  How can this be done?
I have already the regex below, but I can't find an "AND do NOT match 'first' anywhere" (so neither logical AND or a logical NOT).

`(?:(?:(?:last)*.*name)|(?:name.*last)|(?:(?:achter)*.*naam)|(?:familie.*naam)`

but since sometimes "name" also means lastname, it is a match for firstname which I don't want.
I tried adding, but failed with, expressions like this: `[^(?:first)]+`, `(?!(?:first))`, etc.

P.S.
I don't have the libarty of using javascript functions or anything. I have to put this regex into a field of a form of my firefox autofill-addon. So, I need to solve this within the regex itself.

Answer (score 2):

To match anything that does not contain first and is not empty:

```
^(?:(?!first).)+$
```

If it has to contain name:

```
^(?:(?!first).)*name(?:(?!first).)*$
```

You could also use two checks:

```
(str.search(/name/i) >=0 && str.search(/first/i) == -1)
```

Comment: morja, When I test your regex, it still matches "irstname" in "firstname".

Comment: To better explain: som examples: should match: lastname, last name, name last, achternaam. Should not match (at all): firstname, first name, first last name, firstnamelast,...  In other words, from the moment "first" is in there somewhere, I want a complete not-match.

Comment: Yes it will match irstname, but you wont be able to exclude every possible missspelling of first. The regex ^(?:(?!first).)+$ however does not match anything that contains first, as you requested. Tested here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html If you would want it not to match irstname, you would have to change it to ^(?:(?!irst).)+

Comment: "this firstname is bad".match("^(?:(?!first).)+$") returns null; "this lastname is good".match("^(?:(?!first).)+$") returns "this lastname is good"; How did you test the regex?

Comment: actually, i tested it without begin (^) and end($), since I don't think that is allowed in my program.

Comment: What do you mean with not allowed? You are using javascript, right? You will need ^ and $ for a negative condition. But check my updated answer, I added another possibility. Is that better for you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with pure regexp since regular expressions are exactly those recognizable by a finite state machine.

Comment: Most modern regex implementations are capable of recognizing non-regular languages. For example, the regex `^([a-z]+)\s+(?!\1$)([a-z]+)$` matches strings like `"foo bar"` and `"foo fooo"`, but not `"foo foo"` (two the same words).

Comment: No idea why my wishes do not represent a limited amount of possibilites (as what I suspect "finite stat machine" implies)

Comment: I mean "first" wil only happen once in the input.  The only thing we don't know, is where (before, after, in between the rest of the (seperate) words).